# topsep not working for itemize in longtable environment

Tags: longtable, itemize, enumitem

My CV uses `longtable` for each "experience" block, so for example "Work Experience" is one longtable, "Research Experience" is another. I now need to write a few lines of description to elaborate on some experiences and I want to use `itemize` bullet points. For the life of me I cannot get top space before the first `\item` to disappear. Tried `enuitem`, `array`, some other crazy stuff I just copied and didn't really understand. I can get the result I want by using a clunky local `\vspace{-0.35cm}` before every `itemize` list but that makes me want to shoot myself. I am obviously quite a TeX noob and do not want to change my CV structure drastically unless it's simple changes. Obviously required MWE:

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[top=0.8in,bottom=0.8in,left=0.6in,right=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\bf\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[]

\usepackage{enumitem} \setlist[itemize]{topsep=0cm, leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{Name}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{Address}
etc.

\section{Work Experience}
\begin{longtable}{lp{16cm}}

2013    & \textsc{University}, Location, NY \\
    & \textit{Position}, sub-center. \\ &
\begin{itemize}
    \item Conduct research.
    \item Manage people.
\end{itemize} \\

2013    & \textsc{University}, Location, NY \\
    & \textit{Position}, sub-center. \\ &
\vspace{-0.6cm}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Do stuff.
\end{itemize} \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: topsep space present even with enuitem edit for itemize within longtable]

My local `\vspace` workaround works well, but is clunky and I don't want to copy and paste it all the damn time.

How do I get the stupid topsep space to disappear with a global edit? Why doesn't `enumitem` work???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `\setlist` should be declared length units, for example:

```
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=3pt, parsep=0pt, leftmargin=1em}
```

For reducing vertical space between `itemize` and text in the row before it, you can insert `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` start with itemize in above row:

```
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=3pt, parsep=0pt, leftmargin=1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lp{16cm}}
2013    & \textsc{University}, Location, NY \\
        & \textit{Position}, sub-center.    
            \begin{itemize}
            \item Conduct research.
            \item Manage people.
            \end{itemize}                   \\
2013    & \textsc{University}, Location, NY \\
        & \textit{Position}, sub-center.    
            \begin{itemize}
            \item   Do stuff.
            \end{itemize} 
\end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Far less problems you will have, if instead `longtable` you use `description` list:

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.8in,bottom=0.8in,left=0.6in,right=0.7in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\section}{\bf\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[]
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, leftmargin=*}
\setlist[description]{labelwidth=*, leftmargin=4em}

    \begin{document}
\section{Work Experience}
\begin{description}
\item[2013] \textsc{University}, Location, NY \\
            \textit{Position}, sub-center.    
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Conduct research.
            \item Manage people.
        \end{itemize}                
\item[2013] \textsc{University}, Location, NY \\
            \textit{Position}, sub-center.    
        \begin{itemize}
            \item   Do stuff.
        \end{itemize} 
\end{description}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Ahhhhhh I see now. The \\ does that much damage?? Ridiculous. Also thanks for the measurement catch haha. Knew that, just left it out. Cheers, I can go to sleep now instead of obsessing over why the package doesn't work.

Comment: Ok so that got solved. Now how would I go about getting rid of the bottom space at the end of the list? Which argument in `enumitem` controls that?

Comment: Well, you already accepet an answer ... anyway, I upgrade my answer with alternative solution, in which all problems with tale is completely avoided.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to accept someone else's answer! Sorry, I'll change that now. sx noob here, obviously. Thanks for the `description` suggestion. I'll give it a go and see the results

Comment: This works awesome. Thanks for the tips Zarko! One more question: among the `description` items, is there any way to not have any space between one pair while the other ones maintain a standard spacing?

Comment: @Bob, of course. You need to set list's vertical distancesy (`topsep`, `partopsep`, `parsep`, and `itemsep`) accordingl. Package `enumitem` enables do this separately for itemize and for description. This settings are independent from settings of other text.

Comment: Yeah I knew that...Just didn't know what all those options did! The enumitem documentation isn't the best with this. Looks like parsep is the guy I want. Cheers mate, thanks much for the structural improvement

Comment: Unfortunately `enumitem`  hasn't contain sketch of list structure. I usually look into `menman` -- manual for memoir package. There is on page 137. Without it is difficult to manage the all distances: distance between text and itemize is `\topsep` + `\parskip` + `\partopsep`, between items is`\itemsep` + `\parsep` and between paragraphs in item `\parsep`.

Comment: Hm, so is there a way, in one `description` environment, for me to have most items be separated by a constant distance but 2 items close together with no separation? i.e., is there a way to shorten the distance for ONLY two items while keeping the rest of the items spaced regularly? Or would I just have to artificially create a new `description` environment for those 2 items and put them as `nosep`

Comment: @Bob, for one or two exception you ca reduce vertical space by use of a `\vspace{-<amount>}`.

Answer (score 1):

Put itemize into parbox:

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[top=0.8in,bottom=0.8in,left=0.6in,right=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\bf\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[]

\usepackage{enumitem} \setlist[itemize]{topsep=0cm, leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{Name}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{Address}
etc.

\section{Work Experience}
\begin{longtable}{lp{16cm}}

2013    & \textsc{University}, Location, NY \\
    & \textit{Position}, sub-center. \\ &
\parbox{16cm}{%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item Conduct research.
    \item Manage people.
\end{itemize}} \\

2013    & \textsc{University}, Location, NY \\
    & \textit{Position}, sub-center. \\ &
\parbox{16cm}{%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item Do stuff.
\end{itemize}}\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[top=0.8in,bottom=0.8in,left=0.6in,right=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\bf\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[]
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,leftmargin=*}
\begin{document}
\singlespacing
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{Name}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{Address}
etc.
\section{Work Experience}
\begin{longtable}{lp{16cm}}
    2013    &   \textsc{University}, Location, NY \\ % new row
        & \textit{Position}, sub-center.%
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Conduct research.
            \item Manage people.
        \end{itemize} \\ % new row
    2013    &   \textsc{University}, Location, NY \\ % new row
        & \textit{Position}, sub-center.
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Do stuff
            \end{itemize}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

use `letterpaper` and a measuring unit for `topsep = 0`**cm** or just simply `nosep`.

The thing here is, every time you begin an `itemize` environment, in provides a **newline** on the current line after the `&`. (from my observation).

So another solution for this is cancelling the appending of extra rows for the said environment and instead just insert that after `\textit{Position}, sub-center.`

We have the same problem and the unwanted vspace is unconquerable! But I'll let you know if I'll have the answers.
I'll investigate on this one.

For now, this idea I can help you.
Hope this helps.

[image]

Regards,
Gianfranco

Comment: Thanks!! Now how would I go about getting rid of the bottom space at the end of the list? Is that the "unconquerable vspace" you were talking about?